# Por que estes instrumentos musicais são todos chamados de "gaitas"?

Tags: etimologia

Por que tantos instrumentos musicais são chamados de *gaitas*?

Isto é uma gaita [*(ou gaita de fole(s), cornamusa, museta, musette)*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaita_de_fole):

[image: gaita de fole]

Isto é uma gaita [*(ou harmónica, harmona, gaita de beços, gaita de boca)*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harm%C3%B3nica_(instrumento_musical)):

[image: gaita de boca]

E isto também é uma gaita *([ou acordeão ou sanfona](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acorde%C3%A3o); ver também o similar [gaita de botão ou gaita-ponto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaita-ponto))*:

[image]

Além de todas serem instrumentos de sopro, para mim elas parecem ter mais diferenças do que similaridades. Há alguma explicação etimológica (ou lógica) para todas terem o mesmo nome?

Comment: Ora, os 3 têm relação com ar, não?

Comment: gai·ta
(origem obscura)
substantivo feminino
1. [Música]  Pequeno instrumento de sopro.

Comment: 2 primeiros tem vários buracos para soprar, o que diferencia de uma flauta, ou outro instrumento de sopro. alguém entendeu que a sanfona segue a mesma lógica

Comment: Nota: em Portugal, um acordeão **não** se chama sanfona; a sanfona é o que em inglês se chama um «[hurdy gurdy](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanfona)» - é um cordofone.

Comment: Não encontrei consenso sobre nenhuma explicação etimológica, mas achei uma interessante: gaita viria the "gaíth", que é "vento" em irlandês antigo. Veja [este artigo (em espanhol)](http://www.farodevigo.es/sociedad-cultura/2014/09/24/situan-origen-palabra-gaita-vocablo/1099750.html)

Answer (score 4):

Originalmente, *gaita* era um instrumento de sopro genérico. Sem qualificador, o termo *gaita* refere-se à gaita de boca ou harmónica — ao menos na maior parte de Portugal e do Brasil. A gaita dita *de fole* é um instrumento bastante tradicional no Minho e na Galiza, onde pode ser referida como *gaita* sem qualificador.

No Rio Grande do Sul, até ao final do Século XIX, a gaita de fole também era muito usada na música popular, até que foi rapidamente substituída por um novo instrumento, o acordeão. Porque o acordeão passou a ser usado para todas as músicas em que antes se usava a gaita, ele passou a ser chamado naquela região de *gaita* também.

Paralelamente, o acordeão substituiu um outro instrumento no Nordeste brasileiro na mesma época e também lhe tomou o nome: a *sanfona* é, originalmente, um instrumento de cordas friccionadas — chamado em inglês de *hurdy-gurdy*.

Answer (score 3):

Em Portugal, gaita é usada com vários significados, mas esses três da pergunta, não são certamente os mais usados, talvez a *gaita* de foles, mas sempre com «foles» a acompanhar.

> ### gai·ta
>
> (origem obscura) substantivo feminino
>
> 1. [Música]  Pequeno instrumento de sopro, semelhante à flauta e de som agudo. = PÍFARO
> 2. [Música]  O mesmo que gaita-de-beiços.
> 3. [Música]  O mesmo que gaita-de-foles.Ver imagem
> 4. [Música]  Instrumento composto de palhetas metálicas que entram em vibração por meio de um fole. = ACORDEÃO
> 5. [Zoologia]  Orifício nas guelras da lampreia.
> 6. [Informal]  Objecto desprezável. = PORCARIA
> 7. [Calão]  Pénis. interjeição
> 8. [Informal]  Indica irritação ou desagrado.
>
> "gaita", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/gaita [consultado em
> 10-10-2016].

O priberam diz que os exemplos da pergunta são sinónimos de gaita, e talvez, até sejam usados com alguma frequência, embora as palavras mais usadas sejam *gaita de foles*, *harmónica* e *acordeão*, respetivamente.

Eu acho que os pontos mais utilizados, em Portugal, seriam o 1 e o 7 com alguma incidência do ponto 8.

Agora, respondendo à sua pergunta, o que parece ser comum a todos os pontos relativos a música (1,2,3,e 4), para além de serem instrumentos de ar (e não de sopro, no acordeão não se sopra) é o som estridente, agudo (no ponto 1 «e de som agudo») que todos eles produzem quando se toca sem fazer música.

Se repararem a priberam tem "origem obscura" como origem da palavra. Claro que isto é um bocado de *achismo* da minha parte, não consegui encontrar nada que me ajude a comprovar isto, só a minha intuição que me diz que uma gaita que é um instrumento de sopro de som agudo.

Só para terminar eu não fazia a menor ideia que um «acordeão» era também uma «gaita».

Comment: Eu não concordo com o priberam. Em Portugal, um acordeão não é uma gaita, nunca ouvi tal coisa.

Comment: Quanto à origem obscura da palavra *gaita*, o DRAE (*Diccionario de la lengua española*) oferece a sugestão (mas sem explicação) de [“Quizá del gót. *gaits* ‘cabra’.”](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IhUjFrN), ou seja da língua gótica. Há mais informações sobre isso [aqui em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaita_de_fole#Etimologia) e [aqui em galego](https://gl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaita#Etimolox.C3.ADa).

Comment: @ANeves https://youtu.be/rtcVKYUoxUw?t=45s

Comment: Contra factos não há argumentos...

Answer (score 2):

Aqui no Brasil não haveria confusão.  **Os três instrumentos têm nomes diferentes.**

- O primeiro é uma **"gaita de fole"**, instrumento que muitos logo associam aos "highlanders" da Escócia.
- O segundo é realmente o que chamamos de **"gaita"** no Brasil, de norte a sul. Pode também ser conhecida, regionalmente, por outros nomes mas "gaita" é a denominação genérica.  É o que em Inglês chamam de "harmonica".
- O terceiro é um **"acordeon"** ou **"acordeão"**.  Os modelos pequenos e sem teclado são chamados de "sanfona".

Comment: Hmm, então pode-se dizer que uma *gaita de fole* não é uma *gaita*?

Comment: @DanGetz  Sim, da mesma forma que o "porquinho da índia" não é um filhote de porco originário da índia, e nem o "pé-de-moleque" é o pé de um menino.

Comment: No Rio Grande do Sul **gaita** é o 3o instrumento. O 2o é conhecido como gaita-de-boca ou harmônica.

Comment: @Centaurus na verdade, em Portugal também não costuma haver confusão, o costume é chamar gaita de foles, harmónica e acordeão, respetivamente.

Comment: @gmauch - Isso. Gaita ou gaita-piano, por causa do teclado.